# How to show english date (gregorian) in blazor when the current locale is not english

Tags: locale, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Hi I want to show english date beside my locale date, and current culture is not english, how to do this in blazor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c#

```
  DateTime.Now.ToString("D", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

razor

```
<p>@(DateTime.Now.ToString("D", new CultureInfo("en-US"));)<p>
```

Instead of `"D"` u can change the desired format